# Jpa implementing eclipse link with sql server 2008R2

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

Hello i have been trying to persist jpa entity class into sql server 2008 R2 database.But i get some problems.The problem which i'am posting now is already in stack overflow but its unsolved

```
[EL Info]: 2014-07-05 21:06:30.965--ServerSession(2052069)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-07-05 21:06:37.337--ServerSession(2052069)--file:/D:/eclipse/workspace/JpaExamples/build/classes/_User login successful
[EL Warning]: 2014-07-05 21:06:39.741--ServerSession(2052069)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.
Error Code: 156
Call: CREATE TABLE USER (ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL, LOGIN VARCHAR(255) NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255) NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE USER (ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL, LOGIN VARCHAR(255) NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255) NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
[EL Warning]: 2014-07-05 21:06:40.192--UnitOfWork(20389947)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.
Error Code: 156
Call: INSERT INTO USER (LOGIN, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(logon.User@7668ba)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.
Error Code: 156
Call: INSERT INTO USER (LOGIN, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(logon.User@7668ba)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at logon.LogonTest.main(LogonTest.java:29)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.
Error Code: 156
Call: INSERT INTO USER (LOGIN, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(logon.User@7668ba)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4200)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1439)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:885)
    ... 32 more
```

My persistence.xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="User" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>logon.User</class>
         <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>  
         <properties>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                    value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=rithishdb;create=true" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="google" />
               <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
        value="database" />
          </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my entity class is

```
package logon;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: User
 *
 */
@Entity

public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    String Name;
     String Login;
     String Password;

    public int get_Id(){
         return id;
    }
    public void set_Id(int id){
    this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
    }
    public String getLogin(){     
    return Login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String Login){
         this.Login = Login;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
         return Password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String Password){
         this.Password = Password;
    }

    }
```

And my persisting class

```
package logon;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class LogonTest {


     private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("User");
          EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
          // Read the existing entries and write to console


          // Create new user
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          User user = new User();

          user.setName("Tom Johnson");
          user.setLogin("tomj");
          user.setPassword("pass");
          em.persist(user);
          em.getTransaction().commit();

          em.close();
     }

}
```

Can i get a help for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USER is a reserved keyword in SQL. You need to either quote the "table" attribute of the Entity, or change the name to not be an SQL keyword

Note that some JPA implementations (e.g the one I use DataNucleus JPA) do all of this for you without inflicting such database-specific behaviour on the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil that helped me a lot.I couldn't vote you up because my reputation is very low